# Whimsical: Who is that guy on the clojure leiningen homepage?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

The [leiningen homepage](http://leiningen.org/) shows a staid gentleman apparently named "Leiningen". For me, "Leiningen" evokes a [municipality in Germany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen,_Germany). So who is Mr. Leiningen?

[image: A staid gentleman with an extensive Schnurrbart]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the logo of an open-source project, not about any technical aspect of it.

Comment: @pate Where would it be on-topic though?

Comment: Ah, off-topic, but fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mr. Leiningen is a character from [Leiningen Versus the Ants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen_Versus_the_Ants), a short story by Carl Stephenson. See leinigen's [README](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/22acac6b1b9646d107ca1d5667e10b5cbbd755fe/README.md).

Comment: Indeed! Leiningen just stacktraced so I went to the [github page](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen). And yes, there is a citation from "Leiningen Versus the Ants".

Answer (score 8):

Leiningen is the main protagonist of the story [Leiningen vs. the Ants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiningen_Versus_the_Ants) by Carl Stephenson, about a plantation owner facing a horde of billions of ravenous meat-eating ants. Leiningen is only refered to by his last name in the story.

The name was chosen to be a play on the Java build tool [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

The subtitle of the Leiningen tool `for automating Clojure projects without setting your hair on fire` references both Java Ant's presumed complexity and the way Leiningen ends up scorched after having fought through the ants by donning a protective suit and setting himself on fire.

Comment: Sorry Niels I gave @mtyaka the greentick as he was first.

Comment: NP, just wanted to expand a bit on his answer.